# Help with tikz drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to accomplish this drawing:

[image]

My text does not separate into 2 lines and the black line goes over the red circle.  Can you help me to fix this?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick](0,0) -- (7,0) node [right] {Light to the East // of mast means 11};
\draw[black!80,fill=white] (1,0) circle (.2cm) node [left] {Light to the West // of mast means 00};
\draw[black!80,fill=red] (3.5,-3) circle (.2cm);
\draw[black!80,fill=red] (3.5,3) circle (.2cm) node [above] {Light to the North // of mast means 01};
\draw[black!80,fill=white] (6,0) circle (.2cm);
\draw[very thick] (3.5,3.5) -- (3.5,-3.5) node [below] {Light to the South // of mast means 10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For two line text in nodes you should do the following:

- determined node style for more lines with something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=left}]`
- instead `//` use correct code for new lines `\\`

Complete code (slightly rearranged your MWE):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={align=left}
                        ]
% lines with nodes                      
\draw[very thick]
    (0,0) node [left]  {Light to the West\\ of mast means 00}
              -- (7,0) node [right] {Light to the East\\ of mast means 11}
    (3.5,3.5) node [above] {Light to the North\\ of mast means 01}
              -- (3.5,-3.5) node [below] {Light to the South\\ of mast means};
% red circles
\draw[fill=red]     (3.5,-3) circle (.2) 
                    (3.5, 3) circle (.2); 
% white circles
\draw[fill=white]   (6,0)    circle (.2)
                    (1,0)    circle (.2);
% black square
\draw[fill=black]   (3.3,-0.2) rectangle +(.4,0.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Picture:

[image]